# Cordova XCode app build clang error linker command failed on Launch Navigator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I'm trying to build my Cordova app on XCode which uses geolocation and navigation plugins. When I build the app and deploy it on the simulator from XCode it works fine. But when I add the code which uses the geolocation and navigation plugins, the build fails with the following error:

[image: error screenshot]

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to CMMapLauncher.h and CMMapLauncher.m try to rename CMMapAddress and CMEmptyBool to CMMapAdress1 and CMEmptyBool1 for example. 
The error indicates that there is a duplication of these two variables in CMMapLauncher and LaunchNavigator.

Comment: I found these files but am unable to find the variables `CMMapAddress` or `CMEmptyBool` in these files. Could you please tell me how did you figure these variables need to be renamed from the trace?

Comment: im sorry i copied variable names wrong it's : CMEmptyAdress and CMEmptyCoord.

Comment: it is indicated : duplicate symbol _CMEmptyAddress in ... CMMapLauncher.o and LaunchNavigator.o

Comment: I changed these but then it gave four linker errors, in LaunchNavigator.h and LaunchNavigator.m as reference to non-existent variable, and in order to fix these I had to rename them to `CMEmptyAddress1` and `CMEmptyCoord1`, and then on building again I got the same error as asked in the original question, but now with `CMEmptyAddress1` and `CMEmptyCoord1`. Please suggest if any alternative.

Comment: there is 2 declarations of these variables one in LaunchNavigator.h and the other in CMMapLauncher.h right??

Comment: In LaunchNavigator.h, there is no declaration but it is used here: `NSString* startAddress = CMEmptyAddress;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoord = CMEmptyCoord;`. In `CMMapLauncher.h` it is declared as `NSString* CMEmptyAddress;` and `CLLocationCoordinate2D CMEmptyCoord;`.

Comment: These files are available here: https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator/tree/master/src/ios

Comment: did u add `-ObjC` to `Other Linker Flag`?

Comment: remove it and try to run the project again

Comment: Still getting the same: `ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Answer (score 0):

Changing 'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No ( under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation ) fixed the problem.

Source: https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator/issues/92